# Finding a Power Series representation for the function $f(x) = \frac{2}{3-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

Let's say I want to find a Power Series representation of the function $f(x) = \frac{2}{3-x}$

Now I know we can write this as a geometric series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

But I see two possible ways two write it as a geometric series. $(1)$ and $(2)$ below

---

*Method $(1)$:*

We let $a=2$, and $r = x-2$, thus we transform $\frac{2}{3-x}$ into the form $\frac{a}{1-r}$ and we write the Power Series for $f$ as follows:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ 2(x-2)^n$$

---

*Method $(2)$:*

We divide both numerator and denominator by a factor of $3$ to go from $\frac{2}{3-x}$ to $$\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{x}{3}}$$

and we can then write $f$ as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}f(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}\right)x^n
\end{aligned}$$

---

But only $(2)$ is correct, and $(1)$ is incorrect, but I can't seem to see why. What I did in $(1)$ seemed like perfectly valid algebraic manipulations, so why does $(1)$ result in an erroneous answer?

Comment: What is wrong with $(1)$?  (Just be sure it converges i.e. $|x-2|<1$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with $(1)$, but just remember one little thing:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n=\frac a{1-r}$$

if $|r|<1$.

For yours, this translates to $|x-2|<1$.  As far as I see, method $(1)$ is perfectly valid with those restrictions.  For example, $x=2.5$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty2(1/2)^n=\frac2{1-1/2}=\frac2{1/2}=\frac2{3-(2.5)}=f(2.5)$$

There is nothing wrong here.

Comment: SimpleArt, You're correct, there's nothing wrong with $(1)$, I just realized that now, this is what little sleep and copious amounts of caffeine does. Thanks for the answer, I'll accept it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Perturbative Cheers and good sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are quite ok and valid and there are even many more possibilities to expand the function into a power series.

> In order to better see what's going on, we should at first look somewhat closer at the function $f$. We consider the *full specification* of $f$ and choose as domain and codomain
>
> \begin{align*}
> &f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{3\}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
> &f(x)=\frac{2}{3-x}
> \end{align*}
>   Note that we have a *singularity*, a *simple pole* at $x=3$. This is crucial when expanding a function as power series.

As important as  domain and codomain is the *radius of convergence* when expanding a function as power series. 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a x^n=\frac{a}{1-x}\qquad\qquad |x|<1
\end{align*}

It is the radius of convergence which determines where the representation of $f$ as power series is valid.

> If we look at the series expansion of the first method
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2(x-2)^n\qquad\qquad\qquad |x-2|<1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   and the second method gives
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}\right)x^{n}=\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{x}{3}}\qquad\qquad \left|\frac{x}{3}\right|<1\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Attention:** We have to *explicitely* state in (1) and (2) the range of validity since the power series is not defined outside this range. On the other hand $f$ can be defined on a much larger domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{3\}$.

Here's a graphic which illustrates both methods. We  see the graph of $f$ with the asymptote at $x=3$.

[image]

- *Method 1:* The point $A=(2,2)$ is the center of an interval with length $2$ showing the validity of the power expansion. We clearly see the interval  is bounded by the asymptote.
- *Method 2:* The point $B=\left(0,\frac{2}{3}\right)$ is the center of an interval with length $6$ showing the validity of the power expansion.

> **More expansions:**
>
> The graphic indicates what's going on, when we expand $f$ in a power series at a point $x=x_0$. The point $x_0$ is the center of an interval and the length is determined by the distance from $x_0$ to the asymptote $x=3$.
>
> We can now expand $f$ at any point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{3\}$ as follows:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{2}{3-x}&=\frac{2}{(3-x_0)-(x-x_0)}\\
> &=\frac{2}{3-x_0}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{x-x_0}{3-x_0}}\\
> &=\frac{2}{3-x_0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x-x_0}{3-x_0}\right)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(3-x_0)^{n+1}}(x-x_0)^n\qquad\qquad \left|\frac{x-x_0}{3-x_0}\right|<1
> \end{align*}
>
> Of course, setting $x_0=2$ we obtain $\sum_{n=0}2(x-2)^n$ and setting $x_0=0$ we obtain $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}x^n$ and get back both methods as special cases.

Comment: just wanted to thank you for this awesome answer to this question!

Comment: @Perturbative: My pleasure. Your question indicated you could already look  somewhat behind the scene! :-)